# How to create templates in vmware esx 6.7

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, templates

In the esx 6.7 version, there is no template creation option.

I tried this [link](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-FE6DE4DF-FAD0-4BB0-A1FD-AFE9A40F4BFE.html), but no options available as shown.

This is for creating templates, these options also not visible. Please suggest. FYI, I am using the root account and it is a licensed version.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation you are linking to is for VMware vSphere, not VMware ESXi.

The ESXi server does not have the concept of templates, licensed or not. You have to use vSphere vCenter to create and use VM templates.

Comment: Earlier releases we used to install vsphere client but for 6.7 using only web UI. Can you please guide how to create templates for this..

Comment: You can install vcenter with client as VM on ESXi hosts. vCenter comes with 60 days evaluation. Download it from VMware and follow the guide - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/vcenter-server-appliance-6-7-u1-installation-and-configuration-guide

Comment: it is not available here: https://www.vmware.com/try-vmware.html

Answer (score 3):

As Uday said to create templates you need to install VCenter. ESXI itself just support base features. ESXI6.7 create virtual machine dialog box is as follow : 
[ESXI 6.7 create machime dialogbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBF5j.png)

As you can see there is no template feature here.but when you install VCenter you can use more advanced feature like Template,DRS,HA,FT and so on .This is VCenter create machine dialog :
[VCenter 6.7 create nachine dialogbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcidJ.jpg)

But if you can not afforad a VCenter or you don't like to use it because of administration reason, maybe create a OVF from your machine and import it every time you need is a solution. Remember that with template you can create template policies that help you customize templates every time you deploy it.Even sysprep windows machine or change the machine name and ... . i hope this help you.

Comment: Not able to find the product you mentioned in this link: https://www.vmware.com/try-vmware.html

Comment: Can you share if any

Comment: Hi can you explain more what you are looking for?

Comment: If you mean VCenter download link it is here [link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VC67U3B&productId=742)

Comment: As mentioned, vCenter must be installed. Templates in general are a part of vSphere functionality. The following guide might be usefull for OP. https://www.vmwareblog.org/vmware-vsphere-content-libraries-nutshell-use-not/